# MEKA G-UNIT with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I have [MEKA G-UNIT](http://www.ttesports.com/Keyboard/23/MEKA_Gunit/productPage.htm?a=a&g=ftr#.VQ33g98k6V4) keyboard and I really want it to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

Is there any way to make it working, or i have to find other keyboard?

Comment: You should just plug it in and it should work. Sometimes bios has an option for usb keyboards also.

Comment: @mchid Of course i plugged it in, but it did not work.
Now (after some update) it's working.

Comment: You can answer (and accept your own answer as the solution to) your own question instead of providing the solution as an "UPDATE" to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly, after an update, keyboard started to work.